# Reset object rotation information in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a shape that I would like to rotate definitely has its normal rotation is different that the imported one. Here below a saw which was rotated to make the cutting line horizontal.

Unfortunately the blue corners still shows the object from being rotated. I would like to reset the selection rectangle to have only horizontal and vertical edges.

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the object selected, from the menu choose `Object > Transform > Reset Bounding Box`.

This will force the bounding box to reset to it's page-relative state.